# Abstracting out a conditional yield in c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine, yield-return

I am writing a mod for a game written in C# that uses Unity coroutines extensively. There is a programming pattern that is required every time a coroutine is written for mods for this game, that looks like this:

```
IEnumerator e = SomeCoroutineFunc();
if (UseUnityCoroutines) { yield return GameController.StartCoroutine(e); }
else { GameController.ExhaustCoroutine(e); }
```

I would like to replace the start-or-exhaust-coroutine block with some kind of abstraction so I don't have to write the same piece of code all the time. That is, I would like to be able to write:

```
IEnumerator e = SomeCoroutineFunc();
DoCoroutine(e);
```

(or some similar equivalent).

But because the snippet yields on only one path I'm not sure how to do it! In C++ I would use a macro, but I'm not aware of any source-level rewriting mechanism in C# that could achieve a similar effect? Is there a feature of the language I'm unaware of that would allow me to do this?

More complete example code with some context:

```
    public class PureStrengthCardController : CardController
    {
        public PureStrengthCardController(Card card, TurnTakerController controller) : base(card, controller)
        { }

        public override IEnumerator Play()
        {
            // "{AlexandriaCharacter} deals a target 4 melee damage"
            var e = GameController.SelectTargetsAndDealDamage(
                HeroTurnTakerController,
                new DamageSource(GameController, CharacterCard),
                amount: 4,
                DamageType.Melee,
                numberOfTargets: 1,
                optional: false,
                requiredTargets: 1,
                cardSource: GetCardSource()
            );
            if (UseUnityCoroutines)
            {
                yield return GameController.StartCoroutine(e);
            }
            else
            {
                GameController.ExhaustCoroutine(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Obviously I have no control over any of the GameController or CardController code or the broader architecture of the game; I'm writing a mod.

Comment: Can you exapnd upon the context of where this is called? ideally with atleast the method signature surrounding the code you've provided.

Comment: Added a complete (simple) example

Comment: No you can not really do that. It would always yield at least once ... you will always at least need some structure like `if(yieldRequired) { yield return null; }` where the condition itself can be extracted into a dedicated class but the `yield` itself has to happen just like that

Comment: Are there ever instances in your mod where you want to `yield return GameController.StartCoroutine(e)` multiple times from the same method?

Comment: Yep, it's really common that you need to do that multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
public abstract class EnhancedCardController : CardController
{
    public EnhancedCardController(Card card, TurnTakerController controller) : base(card, controller)
        { }
        
    public IEnumerator DoCoroutine(IEnumerator coroutine)
    {
        if (UseUnityCoroutines)
        {
            yield return GameController.StartCoroutine(coroutine);
        }
        else
        {
            GameController.ExhaustCoroutine(coroutine);
        }
    }   
}
```

And then the usage using your example

```
    public class PureStrengthCardController : EnhancedCardController
    {
        public PureStrengthCardController(Card card, TurnTakerController controller) : base(card, controller)
        { }

        public override IEnumerator Play()
        {
            // "{AlexandriaCharacter} deals a target 4 melee damage"
            var e = GameController.SelectTargetsAndDealDamage(
                HeroTurnTakerController,
                new DamageSource(GameController, CharacterCard),
                amount: 4,
                DamageType.Melee,
                numberOfTargets: 1,
                optional: false,
                requiredTargets: 1,
                cardSource: GetCardSource()
            );
            
            // yield return DoCoroutine(e); EDIT: this won't compile! sorry.
            return DoCoroutine(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This will still `yield` at least once

Comment: @derHugo is that a problem? I'm not familiar with Unity at all so unclear how this all fits in the larger picture. Could just as easily have it `return` instead of `yield return` but I'm not sure how "simplified" an example this was to start with.

Comment: @CallumMorrison depends on the usecase of course .. if you want to skip frame only on a certain condition then yes it will matter

Comment: @derHugo from the question though, he's saying he has to duplicate that exact same 3 lines of code in a heap of places (presumably always inside a `CardController`), if the conditional is always the same, and the result of it is always the same, why can't it be abstracted like I've done?

Comment: Hi, I am not sure that the `yield` in the `else` branch would matter or not. I thought Unity does not skip a frame for a `yield break`, it only skips a frame for `yield return null`.

Comment: I'm far from a Unity expert, but from a C# perspective there is no functional difference between my code and the example given. The main reason not to do what I've suggested would involve multiple yields within the same function.

Comment: I'm not sure whether the additional yield is a problem, although I guess I can test it. Just flat returning won't work though - you often need to call multiple coroutines in a single function (for example, if the card being implemented did damage a second time, that would be a second call to SelectTargetsAndDealDamage that would be its own coroutine).

Comment: @JamesPicone yeah, so if you need to do multiple `yield return X` in the same function,  this definitely won't work. You MAY get away with `yield return DoCoroutine(e)` but I wouldn't expect so, there will likely be a type issue at runtime.